# CakePHP Theme?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I try to create a CakePHP application based on themes. I using the latest version CakePHP 2.0.0

My application consists from that files

/app/Controller/AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Session', 'Form');

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->setupTheme();
    }

    private function setupTheme()
    {
        $this->viewClass = 'Theme';
        $this->theme = 'Mars';
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
}
```

/app/Controller/LanguagesController.php

```
class LanguagesController extends AppController
{
    public $name = "Languages";

    public function index()
    {}
}
```

/app/View/Themed/Mars/Languages/index.php

```
// Currently Empty
```

/app/View/Themed/Mars/Layouts/admin.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Html->docType('xhtml-strict'); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <meta name="author" content="Nikos Merianos" />

<title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>

    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
        echo $this->Html->css('amdin.css');
?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
        echo $this->Session->flash(); 
        echo $content_for_layout;
        echo $this->element('sql_dump');
        echo $scripts_for_layout;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

/app/View/Themed/Mars/webroot/css/admin.css

```
body
{
    background: #FA0;
}
```

---

### My problem now

Why the code into admin.ctp under Layout folder in line 11 (echo $this->Html->css('amdin.css');) return the following result :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mars/css/amdin.css" />
```

The problem is that link is incorect. The CSS file is not loaded because does not exists into that path. Any idea please ?

Comment: What is the path actually meant to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

admin should be admin, not amdin

Edit: like Farray said.

Answer (score 5):

Check your spelling...

> /app/View/Themed/Mars/webroot/css/a**dm**in.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mars/css/amdin.css" />
```

You have letters in 'admin' transposed when you include your CSS file...

Comment: A just lower cased all the theme names (into AppController and the theme folder) but no sense

Comment: @Merianos  My apologies, should have been more specific.  Answer updated.